# Remove content of file but not the file itself with windows scripting

Tags: windows, scripting, powershell

How do I strip the content of a file without removing the file itself in a windows scripting environment?

Comment: Found the Clear-Content cmdlet usable with Windows PowerShell.

[technet link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156808.aspx)

Does exactly what I want.

Comment: If that solved your issue, we prefer you post it as an answer and accept it (when you can).

Comment: When you use a term like "scripting environment" at least tell us what scripting language.

Comment: Well, at the time I asked the question, any scripting language executable in a windows environment would do.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this using Windows PowerShell, the cmdlet Clear-Content did the job:

```
$dirtostrip = "$strippeddir\backup_$backupdate\$backupdate\alf_data\contentstore"

$files=((dir $dirtostrip -recurse)  |?{$_.psiscontainer -eq $false})

for ($i=0;$i -ne $files.count; $i++) 
{
    if ($files[$i] -eq $null) {continue}
    if ($files[$i].length -gt $filesizelimit) {
        Clear-Content $files[$i].FullName   
    }
}
```